# Can I make a protocol that inherits from 'View' to display a specific 'View'?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swiftui

I'm trying to make some SwiftUI-Views with similar properties. So I want to make a protocol for them and display an instance of this protocol.

```
protocol SpecialView: View { ... }

struct SpecialViewA : View, SpecialView {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var currentlyDisplayedView: some SpecialView

    var body: some View{
        currentlyDisplayedView
    }

}

//in preview:
ContentView(SpecialViewA())
```

I expect the ContentView to accept my SpecialViewA as a SpecialView. However, in the preview I get 
"Cannot convert value of type 'SpecialViewA' to expected argument type 'some SpecialView'".
and when trying to display I get:
"[...] requires that 'some SpecialView' conform to 'View'"

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close..., but this will compile:

```swift
protocol SpecialView: View {
}

struct SpecialViewA : View, SpecialView {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView<V>: View where V: SpecialView {
    var currentlyDisplayedView: V

    var body: some View{
        currentlyDisplayedView
    }

}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(currentlyDisplayedView: SpecialViewA())
    }
}
#endif
```